# Select a value in all Rows where a DataGridViewCheckBoxCell is checked

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I need to get the all values in the `Names` Column where the CheckBoxes in the `Select` Column are checked when the User clicks the `Add` Button.
These values needs to be stored in an array.

Can someone help me, please?

Here's a screenshot with the DataGridView and Button

[image: img]

Comment: You want to get all the values in the `Names` Column `Where()` the `Select` Cell has value `true`. -- What is the `.DataSource` of your DataGridView set to? -- Do you have any code that tries to accomplish this?

Comment: @Jimi this is the DataSource : `dgvSelectGenre.DataSource = DBCon.ShowDataInGridView("SELECT genre_name AS 'Name' FROM tbl_genre");` And the name of the `Select` column is `colGenSelect` So, I just need to check the rows of the DataGridView `where` the checkboxes are ticked and pass the values in the `Name` column to a array. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're setting the `DataGridView.DataSource` property to what it appears to be a DataTable, but the data source doesn't have a `bool` Column, just a Column that provides the string values, you have added a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn in the Designer; or *manually*, at some point.

In this case, loop the `DataGridView.Rows` collection, skipping the Row at `NewRowIndex`, if adding new Rows to the Control is allowed.

A couple of examples.

**With LINQ**:
Using `Convert.ToBoolean()` to take care of `null` values, since I don't know how you setup the CheckBoxCell Style. In the default implementation, `null` is the initial value of a Cell (you're binding a data source later).

```
var values = dgvSelectGenre.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(dgr => !dgr.IsNewRow && Convert.ToBoolean(dgr.Cells["colGenSelect"].Value))
    .Select(r => r.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

**Standard `foreach` loop**:
Here, a slightly different method, casting to `bool?` the `Cell.Value` and testing `(bool?).HasValue` before `(bool?).Value`

```
var names = new List<string>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvSelectGenre.Rows) {
    if (r.IsNewRow) continue;
    var selected = (bool?)r.Cells["colGenSelect"].Value;
    if (selected.HasValue && selected.Value) {
        names.Add(r.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds good!! Thank you very much @Jimi ... I'll try this one. 